# Como colocar copia oculta a un correo en PHP

Tags: php

he estado realizando un sitio web y necesito crear un formulario con el archivo php para recibir correos, este es el código, no se como poner la copia oculta me pueden ayudar por favor?

He intentado poner lo siguiente: `$header .= 'Bcc: hello@example.com' . "\r\n";`

Pero aun así aparece en el correo el mail de copia oculta

Soy nueva en esto :C

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  
    $mail_to = "asas@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Contacto ";
   
  
    
    
 
    $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," ") , strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"])));
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
    $empresa = trim($_POST["empresa"]);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);
    
    if ( empty($name) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) OR empty($phone) OR empty($subject) OR empty($message)) {
       
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    }
    
  
    $content = "Name: $name\n";
    $content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $content .= "Phone: $phone\n";
    $content .= "Empresa: $empresa\n";
    $content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    # email headers.
    $headers = "From: $name <$email>";
   

   
    $success = mail($mail_to, $subject, $content, $headers);
    if ($success) {
      
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
     
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong, we couldn't send your message.";
    }

} else {
   
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta nuevamente agregando en el `$header` que ya tienes los parametros CC/BCC de la siguiente manera:

```
$header = 'From: ' . $_POST["name"] . '<' . $_POST["email"] . '>' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: ' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" .
'Cc: tumail@dominio.com' . "\r\n" .  // esto sería copia normal
'Bcc: tumail@dominio.com' . "\r\n" . // esto sería copia oculta
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

De igual modo te dejo la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php) de la función `mail` para que puedas comprender un poco mas como funciona el envió de correos en PHP.